# Laravel Notifications How to set Queue ONLY on toMail method?

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-5.6

I have a Notification class with three Channels `('mail','sms','notification')`,

I'm also `Implements ShouldQueue` for queuing Notification.

The problem is that i want to use queue **only mail** or only for **two of them**,in default queuing system sets on all of Channels.

What should i do for this?

Here is my Notification code:

```
class DocumentSendNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $document;

    public function __construct($document)
    {
        $this->document = $document;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database','mail', SmsChannel::class];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
     //something
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
      //somecode
    }

    public function toSms($notifiable)
    {
       //somecode
    }
```

And here is the code that i call Notification class with delay:

```
Notification::send($users, (new DocumentSendNotification($event->document))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(30)));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @lovecoding Yes, but I can't remember on which project I need this :)
Let me think then I share with you the solution.

Comment: @lovecoding You can check my answer, Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your listener class:

```
public $queue = 'YOUR_QUEUE_NAME';


public function queue(QueueManager $handler, $method, $arguments)
{
   $handler->push($method, $arguments, $this->queue);
}
```

Comment: I did, but i did not get the desired result, maybe i did not use your solution properly. anyway can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

if you know which method you want to broadcast do this:

in this example I want only to use database

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}
```

if you don't know which broadcast you should use (I mean it's dynamic and defined in the program and it is optional for the user or something else) do this :

```
public function via($notifiable)
{

    $broadcasts = [];

       collect($userNotificationWay)->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$broadcasts) {
      
       $item && $key == 'get_email' ? array_push($broadcasts, 'mail' ) : null;
       $item && $key == 'get_sms' ? array_push($broadcasts, SmsChannel::class) : null;

    });

    return $broadcasts;
}
```

if one of condition of above code solved to true the broadcast set for it, and call the method to send,

Hope will help